# OWASP ZAP - Extract URL after browser is launched using Selenium Python

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver, owasp, zap

I'm launching a website using Selenium Python! On loading the Chrome browser, ZAP proxy is getting attached to it and capturing URL. I have 2 things to that needs to be clarified here:

1. How to capture URL/requests when user parses through different links? ZAP is capturing it in GUI. Is there any API that gives me the full URL List?
2. How to use Selenium (Python) to capture URL? It captures only current URL and when I go to other link, it doesn't print the new page URL.

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is yes - Zap has an amazing API, and you can find the documentation [here](https://github.com/zaproxy/zaproxy/wiki/ApiDetails). For a longer explanation, I will need some details as I don't fully understand your question.

1 - are you looking to get all the request that were proxy through Zap? You can use the following: `/JSON/core/view/sites/?zapapiformat=JSON&formMethod=GET`.

2 - Not sure - seems like a selenium question, correct?

Comment: I want to know the API which returns me the entire URL list that has been parsed from the Sites Tab for ZAP.
Second question is related to Selenium

Comment: Can you try the API I suggested? it supposes to "Gets the sites accessed through/by ZAP (scheme and domain)"